# messageAdded() method in javamail is not working

Tags: java, service, jakarta-mail, imap

I have implemented the `messageAdded` method provided by `Javamail API` and my program do not enter into that method. Here is my code

```
public void addMessageListenerToFolder(Folder folder, EmailFolderBean<String> item) {
    System.out.println("Add message listener point 1");
    folder.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {

        public void messageAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
            for (int i = 0; i < e.getMessages().length; i++) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Add message listener point 2");
                    Message currentMsg = folder.getMessage(folder.getMessageCount() - i);
                    item.addEmail(0, currentMsg);
                } catch (MessagingException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(FetchFolderService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I added two `System.out` statements, one at the second line of the above code and the other in the `messageAdded()` method the first statement print out every time this method is called but my program do not enter into `messageAdded()` and never print the second `System.out` statement. What could be the reason. Help me to resolve this issue.

**Edit1:** I have a service always running that send a `folder.getMessageCount();` every 10 second.
**Edit2:** I'm testing and its not the final I can increase the time later Here is my service.

```
@Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
@Override
protected Task<Void> createTask() {
    return new Task<Void>() {

        @Override
        protected Void call() throws Exception {
            for (;;) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    if (FetchFolderService.noServiceActive()) {
                        System.out.println("Checking for Emails!!!!");
                        for (Folder folder : folderList) {
                            if (folder.getType() != Folder.HOLDS_FOLDERS && folder.isOpen()) {
                                folder.getMessageCount();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException | MessagingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

And here is the debug info.

```
Deleting: C:\Users\Inzimam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Mail Client\build\built-jar.properties
deps-jar:
Updating property file: C:\Users\Inzimam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Mail Client\build\built-jar.properties
Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\Inzimam\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Mail Client\build\classes
compile-single:
Successful Authentication!
Folder: INBOX
Folder: [Gmail]
subFolder: All Mail
subFolder: Drafts
subFolder: Important
subFolder: Sent Mail
subFolder: Spam
subFolder: Starred
subFolder: Trash
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
Checking for Emails!!!!
debug-single:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 minute 54 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a typo (error) in the code above. I used `messageAdded()` But javamail provide `messagesAdded()` method. So with the right spell and `Override` annotation everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0):

The listener is only called when the client (JavaMail) is notified by the server that a message has been added, and such notifications only occur when you issue a command to the server, such as folder.getMessageCount().  Or, if you just want to wait for notifications, you can use the [IMAPFolder.idle() method](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#idle--).  See also the [IdleManager class](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IdleManager.html).

Comment: thanks for your response. I forgot to mention that I have a service always running behind that send `folder.getMessageCount();` command every 10 second.

Comment: Every 10 seconds?  That's excessive ;)

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show when a new message arrives?  What server are you using?  Ultimately you're at the mercy of how quickly the server notifies the client of new messages.  And obviously I assume you're using IMAP and not POP3.

Comment: @BillShannon yes i'm using IMAP. I added more info to question please take a look.

Comment: It's still missing the JavaMil debug output.

Comment: what type of it is? because I think that is the debug info which is in the last code blocks in question.

Comment: Did you follow my link above?

Comment: @Max what should be the appropriate time gap to call `folder.getMessageCount();`

Comment: Every 5 minutes?  Every 1 minute if your timing is that critical.  Or find out if your server supports IDLE and use that.